# Transferência de Arquivos Socket c#

Tags: c#, socket, cliente-servidor, stream-de-arquivos

Tenho a seguinte situação, Preciso transferir um xml de uma aplicação a outra via rede **(Socket)** montei os métodos de **cliente** e **servidor** que postarei logo abaixo, O arquivo é transmitido sem problemas, Porém arquivos com mais de **6kb** estão chegando **incompletos**, Andei pesquisei uns métodos na rede mas até agora nenhum me ensina exatamente como garantir a integridade do arquivo, Isto é que o arquivo foi recebido por completo.
Tem um outro problema no método abaixo esta travando no **While**, Enquanto eu não der o cliente.close não sai, Porém eu precisava mandar o retorno para o cliente se eu fechar a conexão não consigo, Segue código:

**Cliente:**

```
try
            {
                //Grava o arquivo fisico
                var savedFile = Auxiliares.SalvarArquivo(xml, vendaid, "xml");
                //Pega o nome do arquivo
                var nomeArquivo = savedFile[1];

                //Valida o tamanho
                var nomeArquivoByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nomeArquivo);
                if (nomeArquivoByte.Length > 5000 * 1024)
                {
                    return "O tamanho do arquivo é maior que 5Mb, tente um arquivo menor.";
                }

                //Sepera os bytes e etc
                var fileData = Auxiliares.ReadAllBytes(savedFile[2]);
                var clientData = new byte[4 + nomeArquivoByte.Length + fileData.Length];
                var nomeArquivoLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(nomeArquivoByte.Length);

                //Copia para o stream
                nomeArquivoLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
                nomeArquivoByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
                fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + nomeArquivoByte.Length);

                //Conecta
                clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);

                //Envia
                clientSock.Send(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, 0);

                //Recebe o retorno do servidor
                clientSock.Receive(retornoServidorByte);

                //Fecha conexao
                clientSock.Close();

            }
            catch (SocketException soc)
            {
                return soc.Message;
            }
```

**Servidor:**

```
//Aceita a conexao
                    using (Socket clientSock = sock.Accept())
                    {

                        WriteLog("Cliente: " + clientSock.RemoteEndPoint + " Conectado");

                        #region NEW
                        //Buffer
                        clientSock.ReceiveBufferSize = 16384;

                        //Tamanho buffer arquivo
                        var dadosCliente = new byte[1024 * 50000];

                        //Recebe os dados enviados do cliente
                        var tamanhoBytesRecebidos = clientSock.Receive(dadosCliente, dadosCliente.Length, 0);
                        //Tamanho arquivo
                        var tamnhoNomeArquivo = BitConverter.ToInt32(dadosCliente, 0);
                        //Nome Arquivo
                        var nomeArquivo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dadosCliente, 4, tamnhoNomeArquivo);

                        //Caminho para salvar o arquivo
                        var caminhoRecepcaoArquivos = Application.StartupPath + @"\tempfiles\";
                        if (!Directory.Exists(caminhoRecepcaoArquivos))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(caminhoRecepcaoArquivos);

                        //Escreve os dados recebidos no arquivo
                        var bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(caminhoRecepcaoArquivos + nomeArquivo, FileMode.Append));
                        bWrite.Write(dadosCliente, 4 + tamnhoNomeArquivo, tamanhoBytesRecebidos - 4 - tamnhoNomeArquivo);

                        //Valida o Recebimento (AQUI TRAVA ENQUANTO NAO DER CLOSE NO CLIENTE)
                        while (tamanhoBytesRecebidos > 0)
                        {
                            tamanhoBytesRecebidos = clientSock.Receive(dadosCliente, dadosCliente.Length, 0);
                            if (tamanhoBytesRecebidos == 0)
                            {
                                bWrite.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bWrite.Write(dadosCliente, 0, tamanhoBytesRecebidos);
                            }
                        }
                        bWrite.Close();

                        //Monta o arquivo em memoria
                        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(caminhoRecepcaoArquivos + nomeArquivo)).Replace("\0", string.Empty);

                        //Pega o retorno do SAT e envia devolta ao cliente
                        byte[] arquivoRetorno = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(retorno);

                        //Aqui eu devolveria um RETORNO PARA O CLIENTE POREM
                        clientSock.Send(arquivoRetorno);

                        //Fecha a conexao
                        clientSock.Close();
}
```

Precisa de uma forma de garantir que o arquivo chegue completo e preciso retornar uma mensagem ao cliente informando o resultado do processamento que seria um **XML**, Resumindo o fluxo:
**Cliente envia xml ao servidor > Servidor lê o arquivo e processa > Devolve um xml de resposta ao cliente**

Comment: dá uma pesquisada sobre Minimal Lower Layer Protocol (MLLP) que define caracteres de inicio e fim da mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma, Não sei se seria a mais correta porém foi a única que resolveu o problema, Como o problema eram arquivos que excediam **6kbs** eu ao invés de mandar o arquivo inteiro, O quebrei em "Pacotes" de **6kbs** e on enviei separadamente, Ao final eu uno as partes e o arquivo chega 100%, Segue:

**CLIENTE:**

```
//Coneta com o Cliente
                clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);

                #region ENVIO
                //Pega o tamanho total do arquivo e envia para o servidor
                var tamanho = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.Length.ToString());

                //Envia o tamanho do arquivo ao servidor
                clientSock.Send(tamanho);

                //Aguarda a confirmação de recebimento
                clientSock.Receive(new byte[1024*5000]);

                //Indice inicial do substring
                var startIndex = 0;

                //Total restante a ser enviado
                var restante = xml.Length;

                //Envia os pacotes
                while (restante > 0)
                {
                    //Se o restante for maior que 6kbs
                    if (restante > 6144)
                    {
                        //Quebra a string em 6kb
                        var pacote = xml.Substring(startIndex, 6144);

                        //Incrementa o indice do substring
                        startIndex += 6144;

                        //Abate do restante ja enviado
                        restante = restante - pacote.Length;

                        //Envia o pacote
                        clientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pacote));

                        //Recebe resposta confirmação
                        clientSock.Receive(new byte[1024*5000]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Pega o restante ou total se arquivo menor que 6kbs
                        var pacote = xml.Substring(startIndex, restante);
                        //Abate do restante
                        restante = restante - pacote.Length;
                        //Envia o pacote
                        clientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pacote));
                        //Recebe resposta confirmação
                        clientSock.Receive(new byte[1024 * 5000]);
                    }
                }
```

**SERVIDOR:**

```
using (Socket clientSock = sock.Accept())
                            {

                                //Buffer de recebimento
                             byte[] clientData = new byte[1024*5000];

                            //Recebe o tamanho total esperado
                            clientSock.Receive(clientData);

                            WriteLog("Recebendo dados cliente...");

                            //Retorna confirmação de recebimento
                            clientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("true"));

                            //Recebe o tamanho total do arquivo que esta sendo recebido
                            var tamanho = int.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientData).Replace("\0", string.Empty));

                            //Arquivo xml para armazenar os pacotes ja em string
                            var xml = "";

                            //Recebe os dados e monta o xml
                            while (tamanho > 0)
                            {
                                //Recebe o pacote
                                var pacote = clientSock.Receive(clientData);

                                //Incrementa na string (Uni os pacotes) o valore recebido
                                xml += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientData).Replace("\0", string.Empty);

                                //Abate do total ja recebido
                                tamanho -= pacote;

                                //Limpa o buffer
                                clientData = new byte[1024*5000];

                                //Envia ao cliente a confirmação de recebimento
                                clientSock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("true"));
                            }
   }
```

Testei enviandor arquivo com mais de 1mb e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho algo semelhante, mas as informações são diferentes. Utilizo o MLLP para transferir os arquivos por completo. Segue a implementação:

```
public class SiMLLP
{
    private static byte[] StartBlock = new byte[] { 0x0B };
    private static byte[] EndBlock = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x0D };
    private static byte[] ACK = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x06, 0x1C, 0x0D };
    private static byte[] NAK = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x15, 0x1C, 0x0D };

    private Stream _stream;
    private bool _version3;

    public SiMLLP(Stream stream, bool version3)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _version3 = version3;
    }

    public bool Send(string message)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        _stream.Write(StartBlock, 0, StartBlock.Length);
        _stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        _stream.Write(EndBlock, 0, EndBlock.Length);
        _stream.Flush();
        if (_version3)
        {
            byte[] rsp = new byte[4];
            if (_stream.Read(rsp, 0, 4) != 4)
                return false;
            return rsp[1] == 0x06;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public string Receive()
    {
        int ib = 0x00;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        for (; _stream.ReadByte() != 0x0B; ) ;
        while (true)
        {
            if (ib == 0x1C)
            {
                ib = _stream.ReadByte();
                if (ib == 0x0D)
                    break;
                ms.WriteByte(0x1C);
                ms.WriteByte((byte)ib);
            }
            else
            {
                ib = _stream.ReadByte();
                if (ib != 0x1C)
                    ms.WriteByte((byte)ib);
            }
        }
        if (_version3)
        {
            _stream.Write(ACK, 0, ACK.Length);
            _stream.Flush();
        }
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Utilização:

```
        NetworkStream _stream = this.TCPClient.GetStream();
        SiMLLP mllp = new SiMLLP(_stream, false);
        //Enquanto a flag _running estiver como true, e o client conectado
        while (_running && this.TCPClient.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    //Aqui será retornada a mensagem completa, independente do tamanho dela
                    string msgRecebida = mllp.Receive();

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msgRecebida))
                    {
                       //Processa a mensagem

                       //Aqui envio qualquer mensagem de retorno
                       mllp.Send("ACK");
                    }
                 }
                 ...
              }
              catch{}
              ...
        }
```

Comment: Eu tentei adaptar essa forma no meu mas sem sucesso, No socket eu não consegui utilizar o GetStream teria de ser TcpClient, Eu consegui fazer de outra forma , Postarei abaixo pode ser útil

Comment: Obrigado pela força

Comment: Sem problemas, parabéns pela solução